# Does a Firefox Add-on significantly outperform a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: performance, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have written a Greasemonkey script that is running on all sites checking some things.
Because it runs on every page, performance is important. Thus I wonder, if an Firefox add-on could be faster.

So these are my questions:

- Does Greasemonkey need to reload the script on every page (re-)load?
- Could an add-on increase the performance?
- What are the advantages, disadvantages?

UPDATE:
Some background info - I'm doing a page load latency evaluation on my script.

UPDATE 2 (more information):
The head of my script looks like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        My Script
// @namespace   abc
// @description What it does
// @include     *
// @resource    moz_list  http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1
// @resource    resource_B http://mysite.org/res
// @version     1.0
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @grant       GM_getResourceText  
// ==/UserScript==
```

Additionally I use these technologies:

- Dictionary and array data types
- RegExp for matching links
- tldextract code from here: https://github.com/masylum/tldextract
- JSON for storing and retrieving the dictionary in the cache (could stringify and eval be faster?)
- document.getElementsByTagName()
- window.location.hostname

In pseudocode my main functionality is like this:

```
var host = window.location.hostname;
host = host.replace('www.', '');
if (host in my_dictionary) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (host != links[i].hostname) {
            if (links[i].href in my_dictionary[host]) {
                do_some_stuff();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    send_to_my_server(host);
}
```

Comment: You could always test it. ;)  Don't know if it's still the case, but once upon a... Scriptish was faster than Greasemonkey and about the same as an add-on.  GM is still far from fast and efficient.  If you can think of ways to cache or back-ground process, use an add-on.  Otherwise, just use a GM/Scriptish script.  These ease of development, maintenance and deployment/portability outweigh the minor speed hit.

Comment: Thx for the hint to Scriptish. Sounds interesting. Unfortunately I tried it with my userscript, but it didn't work. And there's nothing special used. I recently got it working with tampermonkey and I don't want to change it for another tool. It's really nuts, that userscripts aren't compatible between different tools.

Comment: Reply updated subsequent to the Update to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the problems with USO, I also got into addons and my experience has been:

**User-Scripts:**

- JavaScript only
- Easy to update
- Mostly platform/application independent (most user-scripts can work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc … and Windows, Mac, Linux, etc without any problems)
- Runs via another addon which affects performance

**Firefox  addon:**

- More powerful with access to more efficient native APIs
- Requires fair amount of further learning
- Update approval/review via official AMO are slow (and on occasions painfully slow)
- Application specific

Overall, if access to the more powerful features (ie access to the browser itself and its APIs) are not required, user-scripts are a lot easier to maintain and the slight performance loss is mostly negligible (I have measured it and the difference is mostly few milliseconds)

**Update:** 
Subsequent to Update 2 in the original post

> GM_xmlhttpRequest, GM_getValue, GM_setValue & GM_getResourceText

Above would be more efficient if native APIs are used (subject to the code efficiency)

> Dictionary and array data types 
>   RegExp for matching links

Similar performance

> tldextract code from here: https://github.com/masylum/tldextract

Personally, I would use my own RegEx in a GM script ...but there is an efficient API in Firefox (`Services.eTLD`) so Addon would be more efficent

> JSON for storing and retrieving the dictionary in the cache (could stringify and eval be faster?)

Similar for JSON .... `eval()` should be avoided (I would never use eval)

> document.getElementsByTagName()

Similar performance

> window.location.hostname

Similar performance ..although in case of addons, sometimes (like in imported JSM) it is more work to get the window and the right one

General Comment:

The performance of a code often can be improved, even as a GM script.
For example:
`document.links` is more than twice faster than `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`

Caching the `links.length` improve speed & efficiency

```
for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) { }
```

`Switch` is often faster than repeated `if ()` ... nested `if ()` can sometimes be joined etc etc

Finally, I would imagine (guessing though), converting a fully optimized GM script to an addon may at best have 10% performance improvement (and involves a lot of work).

At the same time, fully optimizing a GM script can have 4-500% (or even more) performance improvement.

Good luck
:)

Comment: I think he's looking for a solution that shows quantitative performance improvement. But this is a good reply. Do you know if we would see like a 50% improvement on add-on vs user-script?

Comment: Honestly, I can not imagine a 50% improvement on a similar quality of coding (ie not changing the code drastically). Recently, I compiled 6 of my user-scripts into 1 addon and the performance improvement wasn't significant. What is significant is that I have been waiting for a full review on another addon since May 30 and I am now no. 42/170. I also updated 2 other addons last week and the updates will not be available until reviewed. Updates of script are usually available immediately.

Comment: Informative answer :), but Noitidart is right, I am doing a latency evaluation on my user script. Hence performance is important and a speedup would be great. I guess I should have pointed it out more precise.

Comment: The performance difference GREATLY depends on the code. If Firefox's native APIs are used, the performance improves. If the code mostly deals with on page DOM, there won't be a lot of difference. Example: Writing to file would be faster using FF native API, comparing to pass it to another extension to process. Performance of `getElementById()` would be very similar in a user-script and in an Addon. :)

Comment: Good point. According to this, I think the speed can't be increased. What my script does - look if the domain is in a dictionary and if it is then modify the DOM of the page with elements stored in the dictionary. If it is not, then send the domain to my web server. Further the dictionary and the list of domains that are not in the dict are cached. So do you also think that an add-on couldn't bring me a significant speedup? - I will mark this as answer then.

Comment: In the end it will be, I think. But at the moment I'm not sure, if I can already publish it. But I will update my answer with commands and greasemonkey features that I use.